# Loading a file into a PHP script using Curl and Bash scripting

Tags: php, bash, file-upload, curl

Having a `foo.txt` file, I'm trying to load it into a php script using curl and a bash script.

`foo.sh`, `foo.txt`and `foo.php`are all under the same folder:

```
/var/www/foo/
```

The `foo.sh` bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --form "fileupload=@foo.txt" http://localhost/foo/foo.php
```

The `foo.php` script:

```
<?php
echo "foo line";
var_dump($_FILE);
exit;
```

When I execute the bash script:

```
./foo.sh
```

The `foo.php` script shows the `foo line` message, but regarding the file, it gives the following error message:

```
Undefined variable: _FILE in /var/www/foo/foo.php on line 3
```

Any suggestions?

If there is another way to load a file into the $_FILE variable using only PHP (via terminal), it would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $_FILES (so you should add the "S")

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php